# Python IDLE crash on start

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I can run `idle3` from terminal and open a file from it perfectly.

However, if i try to open a .py file directly with it (via "Open with), it crashes immediately with the following log: https://pastebin.com/raw/c2jrNxh9

Python was installed with `brew install python3 --with-tcl-tk` and I have tried reinstalling it and restarting OS with no results. 
Any idea what could be wrong with it?

Comment: Report the situation (work one way, not another), and the log, to the 'brew' folks.  The installing 'Open with' is separate from the file installation itself, and perhaps not done right, at least not for your system.